# Java 8 Streams: why does Collectors.toMap behave differently for generics with wildcards?

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8, collectors

Assume that you have a `List` of numbers. The values in the `List` can be of type `Integer`, `Double` etc. When you declare such a `List` it is possible to declare it using a wildcard (`?`) or without a wildcard.

```
final List<Number> numberList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3D);
final List<? extends Number> wildcardList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3D);
```

So, now I want to `stream` over the `List` and `collect` it all to a `Map` using the `Collectors.toMap` (obviously the code below is just an example to illustrate the problem). Lets start off by streaming the `numberList`:

```
final List<Number> numberList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3D, 4D);

numberList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
        // Here I can invoke "number.intValue()" - the object ("number") is treated as a Number
        number -> Integer.valueOf(number.intValue()),
        number -> number));
```

But, I can not do the same operation on the `wildcardList`:

```
final List<? extends Number> wildCardList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3D);
wildCardList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
        // Why is "number" treated as an Object and not a Number?
        number -> Integer.valueOf(number.intValue()),
        number -> number));
```

The compiler complains on the call to `number.intValue()` with the following message:

> Test.java: cannot find symbol
>   symbol:   method intValue()
>   location: variable number of type java.lang.Object

From the compiler error it is obvious that the `number` in the lambda is treated as an `Object` instead of as a `Number`.

So, now to my question(s):

- When collecting the wildcard version of the `List`, why is it not working like the non-wildcard version of the `List`?
- Why is the `number` variable in the lambda considered to be an `Object` instead of a `Number`?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It's the type inference that doesn't get it right. If you provide the type argument explicitly it works as expected:

```
List<? extends Number> wildCardList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3D);
wildCardList.stream().collect(Collectors.<Number, Integer, Number>toMap(
                                  number -> Integer.valueOf(number.intValue()),
                                  number -> number));
```

This is a known javac bug: [Inference should not map capture variables to their upper bounds](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8039214). The status, according to Maurizio Cimadamore,

> *a fix was attempted then backed out as it was breaking cases in 8, so we went for a more conservative fix in 8 while doing the full thing in 9*

Apparently the fix has not yet been pushed. (Thanks to 
[Joel Borggrén-Franck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38222/joel-borggr%C3%A9n-franck) for pointing me in the right direction.)

Comment: I accept the bet. I know the [relevant chapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html) and I bet it will be *very* hard to sort out why it doesn’t work here, *if* the failure is covered by the specification at all.

Comment: I just wanted to say that for a `Function<? super T,? extends K>` target type the compiler will usually infer the correct types, especially, it will not prefer `Object` for the `? super T` part. Usually. [and that even works when `T` is an unknown type `extends Number`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27901576/2711488). So the only thing that is open is the “why not with wildcards” question…

Comment: Indeed, it compiles with `jdk1.9.0`…

Answer (score 4):

The declaration of the form `List<? extends Number> wildcardList` implies a “list with an unknown type which is `Number` or a subclass of `Number`”. Interestingly, the same kind of list with unknown type works, if the unknown type is referred by a name:

```
static <N extends Number> void doTheThingWithoutWildCards(List<N> numberList) {
    numberList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
      // Here I can invoke "number.intValue()" - the object is treated as a Number
      number -> number.intValue(),
      number -> number));
}
```

Here, `N` is still “an unknown type being `Number` or a subclass of `Number`” but you can process the `List<N>` as intended. You can assign the `List<? extends Number>` to a `List<N>` without problems as the constraint that the unknown type `extends Number` is compatible.

```
final List<? extends Number> wildCardList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3D);
doTheThingWithoutWildCards(wildCardList); // or:
doTheThingWithoutWildCards(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3D));
```

The [chapter about Type Inference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html) is not an easy read. I don’t know if there is a difference between wildcards and other types in this regard, but I don’t think that there should be. So its <strike>either</strike> a [compiler bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8051402) <strike>or a limitation by specification but logically,</strike> there is no reason why the wildcard shouldn’t work.

Comment: Interesting find. Just when I thought I had fully grasped the situation. :-/

Comment: Turns out it's a javac bug. Updated my answer.

Comment: Aren't `? extends Number` and `N extends Number` two different things? The latter is used to restrict the possible types for N, whereas `? extend Number` **is** the type. I think your example qualifies as [helper method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html) and is a nice workaround, so +1.

Comment: @zeroflagL: this kind of helper method is required when you want to modify a collection or, more generally, get a value from an instance of a generic class and pass it back to the same instance. Or when you need to refer to the type explicitly. But normally, you don’t need such workaround for a simple read-only operation as in that context (like here), `? extends X` is indeed equivalent to `ArbitraryTypeParameter extends X`. Both implies an unknown type which has to be assignable to `X`.

Comment: _" I don’t know if there is a difference between wildcards and other types in this regard"_: you may have seen that JLS explicitly distinguishes between "type" and "wildcard" (in particular in 18.2.3), implying that a "wildcard" is not a "type"!! Just saying.

Comment: @Stephan Herrmann: of course, a wildcard is not a type. That was sloppy from my side. I should have written: “I don’t know if there is a difference between *wildcard-parameterized* types and other (parametrized) types in this regard”

Answer (score 2):

This is due to [type inference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html), In first case you  declared `List<Number>` so compiler have nothing against when you write `number -> Integer.valueOf(number.intValue())` because type of variable `number` is`java.lang.Number`

But in second case you declared `final List<? extends Number> wildCardList` due to which
 `Collectors.toMap` is translated to something like `Collectors.<Object, ?, Map<Object, Number>toMap` E.g.

```
    final List<? extends Number> wildCardList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3D);
    Collector<Object, ?, Map<Object, Object>> collector = Collectors.toMap(
            // Why is number treated as an Object and not a Number?
            number -> Integer.valueOf(number.intValue()),
            number -> number);
    wildCardList.stream().collect(collector);
```

As a result of which in expression

`number -> Integer.valueOf(number.intValue()`

type of variable `number` is **Object** and there is no method `intValue()` defined in class Object. Hence you get compilation error.

What you need is to pass collector type arguments which helps the compiler to resolve  `intValue()` error E.g.

```
    final List<? extends Number> wildCardList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3D);


    Collector<Number, ?, Map<Integer, Number>> collector = Collectors.<Number, Integer, Number>toMap(
            // Why is number treated as an Object and not a Number?
            Number::intValue,
            number -> number);
    wildCardList.stream().collect(collector);
```

Moreover you can use method reference `Number::intValue` instead of `number -> Integer.valueOf(number.intValue())`

For more details on Type Inference in Java 8 please refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.1.1).

Comment: The fact that the compiler assigned the type Object to the number variable is pointed out in the question. I think the question is *why* it's not of type Number.

Comment: Ironically, the code in your explanation doesn’t even compile as `Collector<Object, ?, Map<Object, Number>>` is not a valid type for this collector. Due to the value extractor function `number -> number` the compiler knows that the `Collector` must be a `Collector<Number, …`. And since the `T` type argument must be `Number`, it will accept `Collector<Number, ?, Map<Integer, Number>>` as the collector’s type without the need to change anything in the `toMap` invocation as the correctness of the key extractor function can be proved.

Comment: Not a real improvement. What’s missing is the explanation why the compiler should infer `Collector<Object, ?, Map<Object, Object>>`…

Comment: @Holger There is a link to JLS in the answer. Is it not enough?

Comment: No, that’s not enough. An explanation and a link are obviously two entirely different things.

Answer (score -1):

You can do:

```
final List<Number> numberList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3D, 4D);

numberList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Number::intValue, Function.identity()));
```